# Nginx not passing Authorization header when used as forward proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, forward-proxy

I'm building a chrome extension that integrates with the notion API. Since the notion API blocks requests from browsers, I want to set up a forward proxy as a middleman between my extension and the notion API. For that I am using NGINX and docker but the `Authorization` header required by the notion API is not being forwarded.

Docker file:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

NGINX config

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;
    

    location / {

        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://api.notion.com/;
        proxy_set_header Host api.notion.com;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
  }
}
```

Since the Authorization header is not being passed, even though I am sure I'm passing it in the request, nginx still does not forward it but does forward other headers such as `Notion-Version`, and so notion returns an unauthorized access response

Is there something wrong with the nginx config file? There isn't much support for nginx when used as a forward proxy

Comment: I did not. Ended up creating a backend server.

Comment: my situation was a bit different I think, there were some dependency problems with my own server, but for me nginx was parsing the headers correctly